# Bounding the determinant of a sum of identity and PSD

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

I am trying to bound the following expression:

$$\det\left(I+\frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}\left(\Lambda+A\right)}C\right)$$

Where $\Lambda$ is a PD matrix and $A,C$ are PSD matrices.

I know that:

$$\lambda_{\min}\left(\Lambda+A\right)\geq\lambda_{\min}\left(\Lambda\right)+\lambda_{\min}\left(A\right)=\lambda_{\min}\left(\Lambda_{k}\right)+0=\lambda_{\min}\left(\Lambda_{k}\right)$$

The question is, does this bound the original expression, using the above argument?
That is:

$$\det\left(I+\frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}\left(\Lambda+A\right)}C\right)\leq\det\left(I+\frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}\left(\Lambda\right)}C\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that, in this context, positive (semi)-definite matrices are necessarily symmetric.

The answer is yes. Because we are dealing with positive semidefinite matrices, we can use the [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order). We have
$$
\left(I + \frac{C}{\lambda_{\min}(\Lambda)}\right) - 
\left(I + \frac{C}{\lambda_{\min}(\Lambda + A)}\right) = 
\left(
\frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(\Lambda)}
-\frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(\Lambda + A)}\right)C \succeq 0,
$$
which is to say that
$$
\left(I + \frac{C}{\lambda_{\min}(\Lambda)}\right) \succeq
\left(I + \frac{C}{\lambda_{\min}(\Lambda + A)}\right).
$$
It follows that
$$
\det\left(I + \frac{C}{\lambda_{\min}(\Lambda)}\right) \geq
\det \left(I + \frac{C}{\lambda_{\min}(\Lambda + A)}\right).
$$